# How to do combination matrices in tf.Variable?

Tags: tensorflow, session, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have these 2 matrices and I need to combine them so:

[image]

these are them in code:

```
matrix_a = tf.Variable(np.zeros(big_shape, dtype=np.float32))
matrix_b = tf.Variable(np.zeros(small_shape, dtype=np.float32))  

#here I need to combine them
```

How can I do that?

###################################################### EDITED

Thanks to @jdehesa I've written this code:

```
    shape = (batch_size, window_size, window_size, num_channels)

    # the variable we're going to optimize over
    modifier = tf.Variable(np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.float32))

    mask = tf.zeros((batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels), tf.float32)
    # Get input shapes
    modifier_shape = tf.shape(modifier)
    mask_shape = tf.shape(mask)
    # Make indices grid
    oo, ii, jj, kk = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(modifier_shape[0]), tf.range(modifier_shape[1]), tf.range(modifier_shape[2], modifier_shape[3]), indexing='ij')
    # Shift indices
    ii += y_window
    jj += x_window
    # Scatter update
    mask_to_apply = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(mask, tf.stack([oo, ii, jj, kk], axis=-1), modifier)
```

bot now I have this error:

```
ValueError: Requires start <= limit when delta > 0: 28/1 for 'range_2' (op: 'Range') with input shapes: [], [], [] and with computed input tensors: input[0] = <28>, input[1] = <1>, input[2] = <1>.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do that:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Input data (assumes two 2D tensors, `a` at least as big as `b`)
a = tf.zeros((4, 4), tf.int32)
b = tf.ones((2, 2), tf.int32)
# Get input shapes
a_shape = tf.shape(a)
b_shape = tf.shape(b)
# Make indices grid
ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(b_shape[0]), tf.range(b_shape[1]), indexing='ij')
# Shift indices
ii += a_shape[0] - b_shape[0]
jj += a_shape[1] - b_shape[1]
# Scatter update
c = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(a, tf.stack([ii, jj], axis=-1), b)
tf.print(c)
# [[0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 1]
#  [0 0 1 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I want this result?
# [[0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 1 0]
#  [0 1 1 0]
#  [0 0 0 0]]

Comment: @FrancescoScala Then the index shifting would need to be changed to `ii += 1; jj += 1` (you can also avoid the shifting by directly passing the correct `tf.range`s to `tf.mehsgrid`, too, like `tf.meshgrid(tf.range(1, b_shape[0] + 1), tf.range(1, b_shape[1] + 1), indexing='ij')`).

Comment: why 1? Do I have to consider the beginning of the matrix in the upper left corner?

Comment: @FrancescoScala Yes, I mean, I'm not sure what exactly is the specification of your problem, in the first case I assumed it was "putting `b` on the lower right corner of `a`", in the second case I assumed "putting `b` on `a` from the second row and column", so you add one to `ii` and `jj` because you are shifting one vertically and horizontally from the top left corner.

Comment: I need to place b using two parameters x_window and  y_window that are set dinamically!

Comment: @FrancescoScala Then it seems you just need to do something like `ii += y_window; jj += x_window`, I think? Or, depending on the reference point for `x_window` and `y_window`, you may need to use `a_shape[0] - y_window - b_shape[0]` and/or `a_shape[1] - x_window - b_shape[1]`.

Comment: The reference to b is the top left corner, so the first solution sounds good! And if I have a third dimension can I do that?
`ii, jj, kk = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(mask_shape[0]), tf.range(mask_shape[1]), indexing='ijk')`

I keep unvaried k, and then:

`ii += y_window`
`jj += x_window`
`mask_to_apply = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(modifier, tf.stack([ii, jj, kk], axis=-1), mask)` I want to do this because a and b on k have the same size!

Comment: @FrancescoScala With three dimensions you'd do `ii, jj, kk = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(mask_shape[0]), tf.range(mask_shape[1]) tf.range(mask_shape[2]), indexing='ij')` (the `indexing` parameter of [`tf.meshgrid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/meshgrid) can be `'xy'` or `'ij'`). The rest should be as you say, yes.

Comment: @FrancescoScala I think were you wrote `tf.range(modifier_shape[2], modifier_shape[3])` it should be `tf.range(modifier_shape[2]), tf.range(modifier_shape[3])`

Comment: with `tf.print(c)` the output is `Tensor("TensorScatterUpdate:0", shape=(9, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)` How can I print the matrix values?

Comment: @FrancescoScala You seem to be running in graph mode (not eager mode). Maybe you can post a new question about your problem with some code to reproduce, indicating the version that you are using.

Comment: @ jdehesa herethe question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60670157/problem-with-tf-print-for-tensor-unable-to-print-single-values