# Problem with tf.print for tensor (unable to print single values)

Tags: python, tensorflow, printing, tensor

here there is my code: https://github.com/Franco7Scala/RestrictedAreaImageAdversarialAttack/tree/master/src
You should see test_attack.py and l2_attack.py.

Now we can go to the problem, in this place of l2_attack-py:

```
        mask = tf.ones((batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels), tf.float32)
        # Get input shapes
        modifier_shape = tf.shape(modifier)
        mask_shape = tf.shape(mask)
        # Make indices grid
        oo, ii, jj, kk = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(modifier_shape[0]), tf.range(modifier_shape[1]), tf.range(modifier_shape[2]), tf.range(modifier_shape[3]), indexing='ij')
        # Shift indices
        ii += y_window
        jj += x_window
        # Scatter update
        mask_to_apply = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(mask, tf.stack([oo, ii, jj, kk], axis=-1), modifier)
        tf.print(mask_to_apply)
```

when I do `tf.print(mask_to_apply)` I have this output: `Tensor("TensorScatterUpdate:0", shape=(9, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32)` and not he values inside the tensor, How can I print these values?

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 2